# jQuery classic asp firefox best practices for debugging using Firebug/other tools

Tags: firefox, asp-classic

How do you use Firebug or other Fox tools to debug client-side jQuery and see errors and such? I pulled down Firebug but I'm not very proficient. I'd like to do more than fumble.

Comment: Not sure why classis asp is relevant to the question?

Comment: It's not, but I'd rather put more detail in than less. I'm not always certain what's relevant.

Answer (score 3):

In order to see jQuery expressions in Firebug, you need to have an additonal add-on such as FireQuery: http://firequery.binaryage.com/

Answer (score 0):

The most useful panel for debugging javascript/jQuery in Firebug is the console panel.

It will show you any errors which are found, and guide you to the line in code on which they ocurred. It is also priceless for debugging ajax requests, as you will see each GET/POST request as it's made, along with the response text or the error it generates.